# Will my bad karma catch up to me eventually?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

This game features what I'll call a "Bioware-style conversation wheel" wherein there are usually a set of responses possible to any given conversation element.

For instance, if someone tells me:

> Gracius Noticus: Thank you [HERO NAME] for saving my badgers from that evil demon!  Hiljonijiujurr be praised!

And then my responses must be from the following:

- (Left on the stick - exposition) I'm confused.  What's a badger?
- (Up and right on the stick - Heroic) No need to thank me, m'lady.  It's all in a day's work!  Keep your reward so you can afford more badger food!
- (Right on the stick - Persuade) (82.9%) Gimmie more money.  Now would be good.  And any magic daggers you might have lying around your house.
- (Down and right on the stick - Evil) RAWR HERO LIKE TASTY BADGER! (eat badger)

I've got a few points into "Persuasion" so I tend to pick the "more reward/blackmail" option most often.  In most of the games that feature this type of system that I'm used to (for example, Fable or Mass Effect) there are long-term consequences to my actions.  If I'm persistently a "nice guy" I might get rewarded or my appearance might change, or I might unlock special "Hero" abilities.

So far though, I've not seen any indication of this - no "Paragon" points are popping up or any indication I'm gaining/losing "karma" or whatever.

Is there any long-term "karma" system in in this game?  What rewards are there for what milestones on it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no karma system in *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning*, you can do whatever you want and it wont really change anything in the game world (except very few exceptions like the Canneroc village,where you can change the fate of the village but it still wont have any impact on the rest of the game other then the village itself).

Quote from IGN Review by Colin Moriarty:

> There isn't a Karma system of any kind in Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning. You do make choices throughout the game, but none of them are consequential enough to slant you down one direction or the other. Doing something like slaughtering villagers will catch the attention of local authorities, however, who will attempt to arrest you. Then again, you could fight them, pay them off, or break out of jail if you'd like...

So the answer to your entitled question is: No, your bad/good karma won't catch up to you.

Comment: Some Twists of Fate cards are only given to you if the quest ends up in a certain way, but we are talking about 2-3 cases...